# How to show loading image(GIF) until Script function is Finished

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery, loading

I have a html button. Code is given bellow,

```
<div id="apDiv1">
    <input name="wpost" type="button" value="Publish" onClick="wall_publish()"/>
</div>
```

When a user click 'Publish' button it calls 'wall_publish()' script function which is in the **same page**.Code of the 'wall_publish()' function is given bellow,

```
<script> 
function wall_publish(){
       //some codes...
    }
</script>
```

I need to display a loading gif image near my 'Publish' button until Script function is finished.
Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Use [block UI plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/blockUI) to blockui and unblockui.

Answer (score 0):

you should show the picture do the job then remooove it again just that simple

`function show pic();`

`function do job();`

`function remove pic();`

Comment: thos are not functions i am trying to tell you that you should show the pic with a function then do the job and remove the picture again

Comment: oh really sorry.Yes that's what I want to do(show,do my job and remove).But how?

Answer (score 0):

If you have no idea about how to show a picture i think you should go check java-script doc's
if you try to make the pic invisible i can suggest you use the jquery library and just addthe line

`$('#img').hide();` to hide it and `$('#img').show();` to show it ;
this is not very specific but you sshould go throu that

i think you HTML code but not sure

`<img src="the adress of the image" id="gif" />`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to show/remove any html is by making use of the display property.

1. Create a hidden image.
2. function wall_publish(){

   ```
   document.getElementById('loading').style.display='inline'; /* display it */

   // do what you need here

   document.getElementById('loading').style.display='hidden'; /* put it away again */
   ```

   }

There are, of course, a dozen way to do this. I picked the most straight-forward easy approach that I used to use when I first started to learn javascript.

Comment: I used <img id="loading" src="http://myserver/images/loadcomment.gif" style="display: none;" /> to Create a hidden image.
It shows when I clicked the button.But it never disappear when function is finished?